# How to find and replace all properties proceeding with open brace with no colon in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string in javascript

`id: \"test\"\nlang: \"en\"\nresult1 {\n  source: \"agent\"\n},result2 : {\n  source: \"agent\"\n}`

I want to find all words (properties) who is proceeding with an `{` and doesn't have `:` in between, and replace it with `: {` using regex, for example in above string there are `result1` and `result2`,
so I want only `result1` become `result1 :` and the final script will be like

`id: \"test\"\nlang: \"en\"\nresult1 : {\n  source: \"agent\"\n},result2 : {\n  source: \"agent\"\n}`

Comment: I'm concerned about why you need to do this more than how to do it. I got the feeling that you are fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: I receive this data from a third-party, I am trying to convert it to a valid json, and parse it, I am half way through by using https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json, but this library doesn't fix this case, so first I have to do clean up one level and then use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
(\w+\s*){
```

- `(\w+\s*)` - Word characters one or more, followed by zero or more space
- `{` - Matches `{`

```js
let str = `id: \"test\"\nlang: \"en\"\nresult1 {\n  source: \"agent\"\n},result2 : {\n  source: \"agent\"\n}`

let replaced = str.replace(/(\w+\s*){/g, "$1: {")

console.log(replaced)
```

Comment: @Reza bear in mind this covers the general case, if the strings you have is always  going to be somewhat similar to what you have posted in question it will work, if you have any other edge case update your question will extend the regex :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried with my complex string and seems works correct